# Inserting a row in MS Access from c#

Tags: c#, sql

my code is inserting some data in a Access DB. The code were fails is that (the code uses a library for download e-mails, but the error is not apparently related to that):

```
foreach (MimeData mime in email.Attachments)
{

    string name = NumEmail + mime.SafeFileName;
    string path = (@"\\pathrandom" + name);
    mime.Save(path);
    long length = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length;

    String my_querry2 = "INSERT INTO Table(id, field1, field2, field3, field4)VALUES('" + path + "','" + length + "','" + name+ "','" + value3 + "','" + date + "')";
    MessageBox.Show(my_querry2);
    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
}
```

(id, Date and value3 are variables defined out of the foreach with a foo string, date of today and foo string).

When I run this code , the insert does not occur and the `ExecutedNonQuery()` returns a error. It says the query did not run because it would create duplicate values. But the table is totally empty, so the 'id' can't be repeat. I tried to do the query in access and doing it:

`INSERT INTO AchivosAdjuntos(id, field1, field2, field3, field4)VALUES('\\path','171','x.png','random','28/01/2015')`

And it works perfectly (the values are the same that c# try to insert), inserting the values.

The connection with the DB seems fine, because before that insert I've done other that worked well.

So... what I'm doing wrong? :S

Comment: Please don't use string concatenation to build your SQL statements as you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection. Use Parameters instead.

Comment: It complains about duplicate keys. So you are trying to insert two records with the same primary key or a combination of field values clash with the definition of an Unique index in your table. Check what are the indexes and primary keys of your table

Comment: As I said, the only field with key is the 'id' and the table is totally empty, so It can't really be the problem. Further, I can insert the same data since sql, so I can't think is really problem of duplicate. I'm gonna try what Matt said and do it with parameters.

Comment: You get this error also if you insert just one record?

Comment: Are you really using string columns for that ID and the length and date values? Also I hope that your real column names are a bit more descriptive than "field1"

Comment: Sorry I don't read the full question ...

Comment: Another idea. Could you show your connectionstring? Are you sure that the database updated is the same that you are looking at as 'empty'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameters

```
        string my_querry2 = "INSERT INTO Table(id, field1, field2, field3, field4)VALUES(@paramPath,@paramLength,@paramName,@paramValue3,@paramDate)";
        OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry2, conn);
        cmd2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@paramPath", path));
        cmd2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@paramLength", length));
        cmd2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@paramName", name));
        cmd2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@paramValue3", value3));
        cmd2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@paramDate", date));
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Don't know why, but with parameters worked! thanks you and matt, and the other people who told it :P